# mingw/msys with vi, ctags support?

Tags: vi, msys

I'm trying to run vim on win7 inside msys (which isnt entirely necessary, i know i can run gvim in windows, but i'd like to be able to use vi inside terminal)

everything installs fine with mingw-get

but, even after copying over some help files and whatnot, :help TOPIC doesn't do anything because E433: No Tags File

how should I go about configuring my vi correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you put the help files. If you put them in $VIMRUNTIME/doc then execute

```
:helptags $VIMRUNTIME/doc
```

If you put them elsewhere, run `:helptags` with the path to the doc file where you put them, e.g.,

```
:helptags $HOME/vimfiles/doc
```

See

```
:help :helptags
:help add-local-help
```

Comment: After :helptags on ~\.vim\doc runs I still get "no help file", even when i try :help :helptags

Comment: On Windows, by default, Vim doesn't look for anything in ~\.vim--it looks in ~\vimfiles instead. If you want to change your installation so that Vim looks in ~\.vim, you just need to change the value of the 'runtimepath' option in your ~\.vimrc or ~\_vimrc. (Vim does look for both ~\_vimrc and ~\.vimrc, in that order on Windows.)

Comment: ~\.vim is where msys installed it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to juggle too many balls at once and I forgot you were using MSYS, not straight Windows, so ~\.vim is probably the right place. However, when using Vim you have to be careful using \ as a path separator. In most contexts, Vim treats \ as an escape character, so "~\.vim\doc" is likely being interpreted as "~.vimdoc". Try both ":helptags $VIMRUNTIME/doc" and ":helptags ~/.vim/doc". Vim will change the / to \ if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the 'doc' component of the vim package for MSYS

```
$ mingw-get install msys-vim-doc
```